# extract collection from json based on a condition using logic app

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, collections, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to Extract and sum a particular value using group by from json collection in azure logic app. Trying to achieve this by applying "Condition" connector. My Json file looks like below:

```
"Release": [
    {
      "O_Id": "D_13211175",
      "R_ID": "D_132111751",
      "Res": [
        {
          "A_Id": "32323222",
          "F_Qty": 1,
          "I_Id": "828929",
          "OL_Id": "1",
          "Qty": 1,
          "RL_Id": "1",
          "Unique_Identifier": "5970703818904601622__1",
        },
        {
          "A_Id": "32323223",
          "F_Qty": 1,
          "I_Id": "828929",
          "OL_Id": "1",
          "Qty": 1,
          "RL_Id": "1",
          "Unique_Identifier": "5970703818904692717__1",
        },
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to calculate the sum of Qty group by I_Id from array Res using logic app connector "Condition".
Note: As Res is an array, there can be repetition I_Id with same value, hence, the requirement to get the Qty count based on I_Id

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your current flow?

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve your requirement but here is one of the workaround that worked when reproduced from our end.

Firstly, I have initialised a temporary integer variable to iterated inside the "Res" Array using Until Loop by checking the length of "Res" using the below expression.

```
length(body('Parse_JSON')?['Release']?[0]?['Res'])
```

Inside Until I have used condition action to check if `I_Id` is same using the below expression to the left.

```
body('Parse_JSON')?['Release']?[0]?['Res']?[variables('temp')]?['I_Id']
```

and below expression to the right

```
body('Parse_JSON')?['Release']?[0]?['Res']?[add(variables('temp'),1)]?['I_Id']
```

Then if the condition satisfies I'm adding the `Qty` using the expression as below.

```
add(body('Parse_JSON')?['Release']?[0]?['Res']?[variables('temp')]?['Qty'],body('Parse_JSON')?['Release']?[0]?['Res']?[add(variables('temp'),1)]?['Qty'])
```

Here is the flow of my logic app

[image]

[Optional step]
Considering the bigger picture, I have initialzed another variable quantity and added the resultant of Compose 4 to Qty variable

[image]

**RESULTS:**

Considering the below sample JSON

```
{
  "Release": [
    {
      "O_Id": "D_13211175",
      "R_ID": "D_132111751",
      "Res": [
        {
          "A_Id": "32323222",
          "F_Qty": 1,
          "I_Id": "828929",
          "OL_Id": "1",
          "Qty": 1,
          "RL_Id": "1",
          "Unique_Identifier": "5970703818904601622__1"
        },
        {
          "A_Id": "32323223",
          "F_Qty": 1,
          "I_Id": "828929",
          "OL_Id": "1",
          "Qty": 1,
          "RL_Id": "1",
          "Unique_Identifier": "5970703818904692717__1"
        },
        {
          "A_Id": "32323223",
          "F_Qty": 1,
          "I_Id": "828929",
          "OL_Id": "1",
          "Qty": 5,
          "RL_Id": "1",
          "Unique_Identifier": "5970703818904692717__1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the result

[image]

To avoid confusion try the below code view in your resource

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "Release": [
                        {
                            "O_Id": "D_13211175",
                            "R_ID": "D_132111751",
                            "Res": [
                                {
                                    "A_Id": "32323222",
                                    "F_Qty": 1,
                                    "I_Id": "828929",
                                    "OL_Id": "1",
                                    "Qty": 1,
                                    "RL_Id": "1",
                                    "Unique_Identifier": "5970703818904601622__1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "A_Id": "32323223",
                                    "F_Qty": 1,
                                    "I_Id": "828929",
                                    "OL_Id": "1",
                                    "Qty": 1,
                                    "RL_Id": "1",
                                    "Unique_Identifier": "5970703818904692717__1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "A_Id": "32323223",
                                    "F_Qty": 1,
                                    "I_Id": "828929",
                                    "OL_Id": "1",
                                    "Qty": 5,
                                    "RL_Id": "1",
                                    "Unique_Identifier": "5970703818904692717__1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_3": {
                "inputs": "@variables('Qty')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Until": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "temp",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Qty",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Release": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "O_Id": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "R_ID": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "Res": {
                                            "items": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "A_Id": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "F_Qty": {
                                                        "type": "integer"
                                                    },
                                                    "I_Id": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "OL_Id": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "Qty": {
                                                        "type": "integer"
                                                    },
                                                    "RL_Id": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "Unique_Identifier": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "required": [
                                                    "A_Id",
                                                    "F_Qty",
                                                    "I_Id",
                                                    "OL_Id",
                                                    "Qty",
                                                    "RL_Id",
                                                    "Unique_Identifier"
                                                ],
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "type": "array"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "O_Id",
                                        "R_ID",
                                        "Res"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Until": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Compose_2": {
                                "inputs": "@add(outputs('Compose_4'),variables('Qty'))",
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Compose_4": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "Compose"
                            },
                            "Compose_4": {
                                "inputs": "@add(body('Parse_JSON')?['Release']?[0]?['Res']?[variables('temp')]?['Qty'],body('Parse_JSON')?['Release']?[0]?['Res']?[add(variables('temp'),1)]?['Qty'])",
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "Compose"
                            },
                            "Set_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Qty",
                                    "value": "@outputs('Compose_2')"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Compose_2": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@body('Parse_JSON')?['Release']?[0]?['Res']?[variables('temp')]?['I_Id']",
                                        "@body('Parse_JSON')?['Release']?[0]?['Res']?[add(variables('temp'),1)]?['I_Id']"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    },
                    "Increment_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "temp",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Condition": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "IncrementVariable"
                    }
                },
                "expression": "@equals(variables('temp'), length(body('Parse_JSON')?['Release']?[0]?['Res']))",
                "limit": {
                    "count": 60,
                    "timeout": "PT1H"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Until"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I have created Azure function and calling it from my logic app to filter the data.